# Why use `numpy.vectorized` instead of `numpy.piecewise` when dealing with piecewise functions?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, piecewise

I want to draw a piecewise function. There is the code I implemented in Python.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def fun(x): 
    if 0 <= x < 1/6:
        return 6*x 
    elif 1/6 <= x < 1/2:
        return 3/2 - 3*x
    else:
        return 0
    return x

vfun = np.vectorize(fun)

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)    
y = vfun(x)

plt.plot(x, y, '-')
plt.show()
```

[image]

But what if instead of using the `numpy.vecrorized`, I use the `numpy.piecewise` or call the `fun(x)` directly:

```py
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)    
y = fun(x)
```

```py
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)   
y = np.piecewise(x, [x < 1/6, 1/6 <= x < 1/2, x >= 1/2], [lambda x: 6*x, lambda x: 3/2 - 3*x, lambda x: 0])
```

They all make the same error：

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I want to figure out why we need `vectorized` functions to express piecewise functions exactly. What does it do to the function?

Comment: `x < 1<6` - really?

Comment: Just use  `y = np.array([fun(i) for i in x])` and skip the drama.  You can't use `1<x<5` with an array.  And can't use an array in an `if` clause.

Comment: @hpaulj I am so sorry, it should be `x < 1/6`. Thank you for your answer, but I still want to know why `y = vfun(x)` it can work. Because in my study, I often use the idea of vectorized programming.

Comment: The final `return x` in `fun()` is useless (dead code).

Comment: @norok2 This line of code is really redundant. Thanks for your reminding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `x < value` where `x` is a NumPy array produces a boolean array. To combine multiple boolean arrays you would need a boolean operator. To get the same meaning as `value1 < x < value2` you would need a bitwise-and operator `&`: `(value1 < x) & (x < value2)`.
Hence, you can re-write `fun()` with piecewise like:

```py
def fun_piecewise(
    arr,
    pieces,
    funcs=(lambda x: 0, lambda x: 6 * x, lambda x: 3 / 2 - 3 * x, lambda x: 0)
):
    return np.piecewise(x, pieces, funcs)


fun_piecewise(x, (x < 0, (0 <= x) & (x < 1/6), (1/6 <= x) & (x < 1/2), x >= 1/2))
```

I would recommend writing your own function using masking more efficiently than what `np.piecewise()` can:

```py
def fun_np(
    arr,
    thresholds=(0, 1/6, 1/2),
    funcs=(lambda x: 0, lambda x: 6 * x, lambda x: 3 / 2 - 3 * x, lambda x: 0)
):
    masks = np.array([arr < threshold for threshold in thresholds])
    masks = [masks[0]] + [x for x in masks[1:] & ~masks[:-1]] + [~masks[-1]]
    result = np.empty_like(arr)
    for mask, func in zip(masks, funcs):
        result[mask] = func(arr[mask])
    return result
```

The idea is that the masks are combined pairwise (except the first and the last) so there is no need to recompute them twice.
Note that there is one function more than thresholds, because of the edge/bin effect (to define `n` bins one needs `n + 1` edges) combined with the fact that the -∞ and +∞ edges are implicit.

This is typically faster than both `vfun()` and `np.piecewise()`.
Memory-wise `vfun()` is more efficient:

```py
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 1000)

%timeit vfun(x)
# 284 µs ± 10.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit fun_np(x)
# 36.6 µs ± 2.04 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit fun_piecewise(x, (x < 0, (0 <= x) & (x < 1/6), (1/6 <= x) & (x < 1/2), x >= 1/2))
# 56.2 µs ± 2.04 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit np.array([fun(i) for i in x])
# 695 µs ± 10.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved my problem. I learned a lot from the operation of masks.